# Power BI or Excel 2019 Power Query not connecting to "BOE" webpage

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

I am using Windows 10 Pro with Excel 2019 (32 bits) and Power BI desktop (64 bits) to try to connect to the BOE webpage
[webpage](https://www.boe.es/diario_boe/txt.php?id=BOE-A-2020-17270) using the Web connector and extract some tables.

I am using a regular laptop, I am not using a proxy or a VPN, since it is a public document.

I have tried accessing the pdf document version (downloaded to my PC) and other variants including the XML link or document or the Permalink (that follows the ELI format by BOE as described in Spanish in https://www.boe.es/legislacion/eli.php).

Webpage with Permalink ELI
https://www.boe.es/eli/es/o/2020/12/28/hac1275/dof/spa/html

It is quite a big document and page, and after ~5 min I get an error message "DataSource.Error. Timeout".

Any idea or suggestion?

Update:
I tried with Timeout set to 15 min and got same Error Message.
In Excel I got an error message as well with these details:

```
Feedback Type:
Frown (Error)

Error Message:
Error

Stack Trace:


Stack Trace Message:
Error

Invocation Stack Trace:
   en Microsoft.Mashup.Host.Document.ExceptionExtensions.GetCurrentInvocationStackTrace()
   en Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.StackTraceInfo..ctor(String exceptionStackTrace, String invocationStackTrace, String exceptionMessage)
   en Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.FeedbackErrorInfo..ctor(String message, Exception exception, Nullable`1 stackTraceInfo, String messageDetail)
   en Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Windows.UIHost.RaiseErrorDialog(IWindowHandle activeWindow, FeedbackPackageInfo feedbackPackageInfo, Exception e, LocalizedString dialogTitle, LocalizedString dialogMessage, Boolean useGDICapture)
   en Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.Native.NativeUserFeedbackServices.ReportException(IWindowHandle activeWindow, IUIHost uiHost, FeedbackPackageInfo feedbackPackageInfo, Exception e, Boolean useGDICapture)
   en Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.UnexpectedExceptionHandler.<>c__DisplayClass15_0.<HandleException>b__0()
   en Microsoft.Mashup.Host.Document.SynchronizationContextExtensions.SendAndMarshalExceptions(SynchronizationContext context, Action callback)
   en Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.UnexpectedExceptionHandler.HandleException(Exception e)
   en Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.DataImporter.HandleImportEvaluationException(ExceptionResult exceptionView, Query query, String sourceID, String formulaTitle, Boolean isNewQuery, Boolean isFromEditor)
   en Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.DataImporter.OnGetPreviewResult(PreviewResult preview, Query query, String sourceID, String formulaTitle, Nullable`1 explicitImportDestination, Boolean isNewQuery, Boolean isFromEditor)
   en Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.DataImporter.GetPreviewResult(Query query, String sourceID, String formulaTitle, Boolean isNewQuery, Boolean isFromEditor, Nullable`1 explicitImportDestination)
   en Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.ExcelDataImporter.<>c__DisplayClass62_0.<GetPreviewResult>b__1()
   en Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.Shim.NativeWorkbookStorageServices.Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.Shim.IDeferredStorageInvoker.InvokeDeferredStorageAction(IWorkbook workbook, Action action)
   en Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.Shim.NativeCoAuthServices.InvokeCoauthAction(IWorkbook workbook, UndoableActionType actionType, Action action)
   en Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.ExcelDataImporter.<>c__DisplayClass62_0.<GetPreviewResult>b__0(IWorkbook workbook)
   en Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.ExcelDataImporter.<>c__DisplayClass55_1.<NotifyGetDataPresence>b__1()
   en Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.Shim.NativeCoAuthServices.NotifyGetDataPresence(IWorkbook workbook, Action action)
   en Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.ExcelDataImporter.<>c__DisplayClass55_0.<NotifyGetDataPresence>b__0(IWorkbook workbook)
   en Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.ExcelDataImporter.<>c__DisplayClass56_0.<InvokeOnWorkbook>b__0(IWorkbook workbook, IWindowContext windowContext)
   en Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.ExcelDataImporter.InvokeOnWorkbook[T](Func`3 action, T defaultValue)
   en Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.ExcelDataImporter.InvokeOnWorkbook(Action`1 action)
   en Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.ExcelDataImporter.NotifyGetDataPresence(Action`1 action)
   en Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.ExcelDataImporter.GetPreviewResult(Query query, String sourceID, String formulaTitle, Boolean isNewQuery, Boolean isFromEditor, Nullable`1 explicitImportDestination)
   en Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.DataImporter.<>c__DisplayClass86_1.<OnQuerySettingsResolved>b__0()
   en Microsoft.Mashup.Host.Document.ExceptionHandlerExtensions.HandleExceptions(IExceptionHandler exceptionHandler, Action action)
   en Microsoft.Mashup.Host.Document.SynchronizationContextExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<Post>b__0(Object null)
   en System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   en System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   en System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)
   en System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackDo(ThreadMethodEntry tme)
   en System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackHelper(Object obj)
   en System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   en System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   en System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   en System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallback(ThreadMethodEntry tme)
   en System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbacks()
   en System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   en System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   en System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   en System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)


InnerException0.Stack Trace Message:
Container exited unexpectedly with code 0x40010004. PID: 31728.
Used features: (none).

InnerException0.Stack Trace:
   en Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.ErrorTranslatingMessenger.MessageChannel.Read()
   en Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.ChannelMessenger.Read(MessageChannel channel)
   en Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.ChannelMessenger.MessageChannel.Read()
   en Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.Interface.IMessageChannelExtensions.WaitFor[T](IMessageChannel channel)
   en Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.RemotePreviewValueSource.PreviewValueSource.WaitFor(Func`1 condition, Boolean disposing)
   en Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.RemotePreviewValueSource.PreviewValueSource.get_TableSource()
   en Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.Interface.TracingPreviewValueSource.get_TableSource()
   en Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.Interface.NotifyingPreviewValueSource.get_TableSource()
   en Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.Interface.NotifyingPreviewValueSource.get_TableSource()
   en Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.Interface.NotifyingPreviewValueSource.get_TableSource()
   en Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.Interface.NotifyingPreviewValueSource.get_TableSource()
   en Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.Interface.NotifyingPreviewValueSource.get_TableSource()
   en Microsoft.Mashup.Host.Document.Analysis.PackageDocumentAnalysisInfo.PackagePartitionAnalysisInfo.SetPreviewValue(EvaluationResult2`1 result, Func`1 getStaleSince, Func`1 getSampled)

InnerException0.Invocation Stack Trace:
   en Microsoft.Mashup.Host.Document.ExceptionExtensions.GetCurrentInvocationStackTrace()
   en Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.StackTraceInfo..ctor(String exceptionStackTrace, String invocationStackTrace, String exceptionMessage)
   en Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.FeedbackErrorInfo.GetFeedbackValuesFromException(Exception e, String prefix)
   en Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.FeedbackErrorInfo.GetFeedbackValuesFromInnerExceptions(Exception e, Int32 depth)
   en Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.FeedbackErrorInfo.CreateAdditionalErrorInfo(Exception e)
   en Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.FeedbackErrorInfo..ctor(String message, Exception exception, Nullable`1 stackTraceInfo, String messageDetail)
   en Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Windows.UIHost.RaiseErrorDialog(IWindowHandle activeWindow, FeedbackPackageInfo feedbackPackageInfo, Exception e, LocalizedString dialogTitle, LocalizedString dialogMessage, Boolean useGDICapture)
   en Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.Native.NativeUserFeedbackServices.ReportException(IWindowHandle activeWindow, IUIHost uiHost, FeedbackPackageInfo feedbackPackageInfo, Exception e, Boolean useGDICapture)
   en Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.UnexpectedExceptionHandler.<>c__DisplayClass15_0.<HandleException>b__0()
   en Microsoft.Mashup.Host.Document.SynchronizationContextExtensions.SendAndMarshalExceptions(SynchronizationContext context, Action callback)
   en Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.UnexpectedExceptionHandler.HandleException(Exception e)
   en Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.DataImporter.HandleImportEvaluationException(ExceptionResult exceptionView, Query query, String sourceID, String formulaTitle, Boolean isNewQuery, Boolean isFromEditor)
   en Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.DataImporter.OnGetPreviewResult(PreviewResult preview, Query query, String sourceID, String formulaTitle, Nullable`1 explicitImportDestination, Boolean isNewQuery, Boolean isFromEditor)
   en Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.DataImporter.GetPreviewResult(Query query, String sourceID, String formulaTitle, Boolean isNewQuery, Boolean isFromEditor, Nullable`1 explicitImportDestination)
   en Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.ExcelDataImporter.<>c__DisplayClass62_0.<GetPreviewResult>b__1()
   en Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.Shim.NativeWorkbookStorageServices.Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.Shim.IDeferredStorageInvoker.InvokeDeferredStorageAction(IWorkbook workbook, Action action)
   en Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.Shim.NativeCoAuthServices.InvokeCoauthAction(IWorkbook workbook, UndoableActionType actionType, Action action)
   en Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.ExcelDataImporter.<>c__DisplayClass62_0.<GetPreviewResult>b__0(IWorkbook workbook)
   en Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.ExcelDataImporter.<>c__DisplayClass55_1.<NotifyGetDataPresence>b__1()
   en Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.Shim.NativeCoAuthServices.NotifyGetDataPresence(IWorkbook workbook, Action action)
   en Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.ExcelDataImporter.<>c__DisplayClass55_0.<NotifyGetDataPresence>b__0(IWorkbook workbook)
   en Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.ExcelDataImporter.<>c__DisplayClass56_0.<InvokeOnWorkbook>b__0(IWorkbook workbook, IWindowContext windowContext)
   en Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.ExcelDataImporter.InvokeOnWorkbook[T](Func`3 action, T defaultValue)
   en Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.ExcelDataImporter.InvokeOnWorkbook(Action`1 action)
   en Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.ExcelDataImporter.NotifyGetDataPresence(Action`1 action)
   en Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.ExcelDataImporter.GetPreviewResult(Query query, String sourceID, String formulaTitle, Boolean isNewQuery, Boolean isFromEditor, Nullable`1 explicitImportDestination)
   en Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.DataImporter.<>c__DisplayClass86_1.<OnQuerySettingsResolved>b__0()
   en Microsoft.Mashup.Host.Document.ExceptionHandlerExtensions.HandleExceptions(IExceptionHandler exceptionHandler, Action action)
   en Microsoft.Mashup.Host.Document.SynchronizationContextExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<Post>b__0(Object null)
   en System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   en System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   en System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)
   en System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackDo(ThreadMethodEntry tme)
   en System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackHelper(Object obj)
   en System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   en System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   en System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   en System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallback(ThreadMethodEntry tme)
   en System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbacks()
   en System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   en System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   en System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   en System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)


InnerException1.Stack Trace Message:
Container exited unexpectedly with code 0x40010004. PID: 31728.

InnerException1.Stack Trace:
   en Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.ErrorTranslatingMessenger.MessageChannel.Read()
   en Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.ErrorTranslatingMessenger.MessageChannel.Read()

InnerException1.Invocation Stack Trace:
   en Microsoft.Mashup.Host.Document.ExceptionExtensions.GetCurrentInvocationStackTrace()
   en Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.StackTraceInfo..ctor(String exceptionStackTrace, String invocationStackTrace, String exceptionMessage)
   en Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.FeedbackErrorInfo.GetFeedbackValuesFromException(Exception e, String prefix)
   en Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.FeedbackErrorInfo.GetFeedbackValuesFromInnerExceptions(Exception e, Int32 depth)
   en Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.FeedbackErrorInfo.GetFeedbackValuesFromInnerExceptions(Exception e, Int32 depth)
   en Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.FeedbackErrorInfo.CreateAdditionalErrorInfo(Exception e)
   en Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.FeedbackErrorInfo..ctor(String message, Exception exception, Nullable`1 stackTraceInfo, String messageDetail)
   en Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Windows.UIHost.RaiseErrorDialog(IWindowHandle activeWindow, FeedbackPackageInfo feedbackPackageInfo, Exception e, LocalizedString dialogTitle, LocalizedString dialogMessage, Boolean useGDICapture)
   en Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.Native.NativeUserFeedbackServices.ReportException(IWindowHandle activeWindow, IUIHost uiHost, FeedbackPackageInfo feedbackPackageInfo, Exception e, Boolean useGDICapture)
   en Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.UnexpectedExceptionHandler.<>c__DisplayClass15_0.<HandleException>b__0()
   en Microsoft.Mashup.Host.Document.SynchronizationContextExtensions.SendAndMarshalExceptions(SynchronizationContext context, Action callback)
   en Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.UnexpectedExceptionHandler.HandleException(Exception e)
   en Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.DataImporter.HandleImportEvaluationException(ExceptionResult exceptionView, Query query, String sourceID, String formulaTitle, Boolean isNewQuery, Boolean isFromEditor)
   en Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.DataImporter.OnGetPreviewResult(PreviewResult preview, Query query, String sourceID, String formulaTitle, Nullable`1 explicitImportDestination, Boolean isNewQuery, Boolean isFromEditor)
   en Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.DataImporter.GetPreviewResult(Query query, String sourceID, String formulaTitle, Boolean isNewQuery, Boolean isFromEditor, Nullable`1 explicitImportDestination)
   en Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.ExcelDataImporter.<>c__DisplayClass62_0.<GetPreviewResult>b__1()
   en Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.Shim.NativeWorkbookStorageServices.Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.Shim.IDeferredStorageInvoker.InvokeDeferredStorageAction(IWorkbook workbook, Action action)
   en Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.Shim.NativeCoAuthServices.InvokeCoauthAction(IWorkbook workbook, UndoableActionType actionType, Action action)
   en Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.ExcelDataImporter.<>c__DisplayClass62_0.<GetPreviewResult>b__0(IWorkbook workbook)
   en Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.ExcelDataImporter.<>c__DisplayClass55_1.<NotifyGetDataPresence>b__1()
   en Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.Shim.NativeCoAuthServices.NotifyGetDataPresence(IWorkbook workbook, Action action)
   en Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.ExcelDataImporter.<>c__DisplayClass55_0.<NotifyGetDataPresence>b__0(IWorkbook workbook)
   en Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.ExcelDataImporter.<>c__DisplayClass56_0.<InvokeOnWorkbook>b__0(IWorkbook workbook, IWindowContext windowContext)
   en Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.ExcelDataImporter.InvokeOnWorkbook[T](Func`3 action, T defaultValue)
   en Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.ExcelDataImporter.InvokeOnWorkbook(Action`1 action)
   en Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.ExcelDataImporter.NotifyGetDataPresence(Action`1 action)
   en Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.ExcelDataImporter.GetPreviewResult(Query query, String sourceID, String formulaTitle, Boolean isNewQuery, Boolean isFromEditor, Nullable`1 explicitImportDestination)
   en Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.DataImporter.<>c__DisplayClass86_1.<OnQuerySettingsResolved>b__0()
   en Microsoft.Mashup.Host.Document.ExceptionHandlerExtensions.HandleExceptions(IExceptionHandler exceptionHandler, Action action)
   en Microsoft.Mashup.Host.Document.SynchronizationContextExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<Post>b__0(Object null)
   en System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   en System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   en System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)
   en System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackDo(ThreadMethodEntry tme)
   en System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackHelper(Object obj)
   en System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   en System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   en System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   en System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallback(ThreadMethodEntry tme)
   en System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbacks()
   en System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   en System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   en System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   en System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)


Supports Premium Content:
True

Formulas:


section Section1;

shared html = let
    Origen = Web.Page(Web.Contents("https://www.boe.es/eli/es/o/2020/12/28/hac1275/dof/spa/html", [Timeout=#duration(0, 0, 15, 0)]))
in
    Origen;
```

Comment: Please checkout the How to ask Questions Guide https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Your question is unspecific about your environment. E.g. do you have an Http proxy or are using a VPN client etc.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried set custom timeout?

[image]

Comment: I tried but, got same error in Power BI. In Excel I got also an error message with these details: